# Enable or Disable permissions for App in Android applicaton

Tags: android, permissions

I am new to android development. I have written a loop which go thru all installed applications. And it lists out permissions that are used by each applications.  Now I am trying to allow user to disable or enable permission. For example if an App uses SEND_SMS, then user should be able to disable that permission for that application. And if user should be able to enable back if s/he want it back. Can some body provide me idea on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to add or remove permission dynamically at run time. You must declare them at the manifest.

Perhaps you can do one thing. You can just get user's wish to enable disable a feature and handle it by your own. I dont see any need of chaning permission dynamically for this case.
Say if user disable sms sending from settings then just dont send sms from your application. Why do you need the change the permission for this?

Another example. Say you need to receive a broadcast which needs a permission. So disable the broadcastreceiver just unregister the receiver.

So in all cases you can disable or enable your features. So the main issue is to enable/disable feature not enabling/disabling permission

Comment: May be I am not asking this question in right way. Let me try to explain agian. I am trying to build an app like one that you find in the following URL. This App allows you to disable permission for specific App. For example: let's say Angry Bird App reads your phone-call logs, and sends usages via SMS to its vendor. And now I want to disable these permissions which was orginally granted for reading Phone-call, and sending SMS to Angry Bird Vendor. 
http://www.howtogeek.com/115888/how-to-restrict-android-app-permissions/

Comment: Your link is saying it all.. you will need a rooted device for that